# What could cause my newly installed disposal to not work?

Tags: electrical, garbage-disposal

I just replaced my garbage disposal. Completed install. Darned thing won't start. Checked the wire nuts two and three times. Nothing. Ideas?

Comment: how is the power supplied? Is it plugged into a GFI under the sink that may be tripped. Is it switched via a wall switch. Try the reset button on the dispsal unit.

Comment: Have you verified that power is reaching the wires (preferably with a non-contact tester). If so, then the disposal is either broken or you missed a step in the instructions.

Comment: Power is to a junction box mounted on the wall under the sink. The junction box is wired to a switch on the wall above the sink. I checked the wire nuts inside the junction box, too.

Comment: BMitch, I don't know how to verify if power is reaching the wires. I'm pretty sure I didn't miss a step in the instructions.

Comment: what model disposal do you have?  Is there a red button reset on the unit? Does it make any noise at all when you turn the switch on?

Comment: Also check the breaker in the panel and the GFIC reset in the kitchen.

Comment: @Ronnie, if you don't know how to check for power on electrical lines, then you shouldn't be working on your home's electrical system. This is a basic safety step that could result in injury, fire, or death if skipped. I'd recommend you hire a professional.

Comment: Folks, turned out that I installed it right but the switch failed. Used a circuit tester to find the problem. Changed out the switch and was good to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your new disposal should be connected to a switched GFCI outlet.

Verify that the outlet is not tripped.

Using an [outlet tester](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002LZTKIA), 
verify that the switch properly powers the electrical socket.

Many disposals have an integrated breaker. Locate this switch and verify that the disposal itself has not tripped. You could also try plugging the disposal into an extension cord into a known-good outlet and verify that it operates properly.

Verify that the disposal is not jammed. All modern disposals have an allan socket beneath them which manually turn the blades. Make sure this moves freely.

Following all of the previous trouble-shooting tests, replace the disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Get one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter) and make sure power is going to the wires that you connected to the disposal unit.

Comment: If you just have a bit of extra information to add, consider adding it as a comment instead of an answer.  If you expand on this answer a bit, it could probably be a really good one. As it stands now, it's not very helpful to a person who has limited to no experience with multimeters or electrical work.  Consider adding some information on how to make sure there is power going to the wires with a multimeter, and/or maybe some ideas of what to do if power is/isn't there.